# Hamburger-menu в один файл

Tags: android, xml

Одна из вещей, которая мне не нравится в программировании под Android - это уйма файлов, соответствующих одному элементу (например, Hamburger menu). Ну, или может это в шаблонах Android studio так. Так или иначе, в этом вопросе я хочу узнать, как можно собрать в один файл **Hamburger menu** из шаблона `Navigation Drawer Activity` среды Android Studio, но это пригодится в других ситуациях, когда файлов слишком много. На данный момент Hamburger menu "собирается" как минимум из 3 файлов:

**nav_header_main.xml** - верхняя часть выдвижного меню:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="Android Studio"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="android.studio@android.com" />

</LinearLayout>
```

- **side_nav_bar.xml** - заливка фона верхней части меню (код не хочет отображаться):
- **activity_main_drawer.xml** - пункты меню:

  ```
  <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
      <item
          android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
          android:title="Import" />
      <item
          android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
          android:title="Gallery" />
      <item
          android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
          android:title="Slideshow" />
      <item
          android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
          android:title="Tools" />
  </group>

  <item android:title="Communicate">
      <menu>
          <item
              android:id="@+id/nav_share"
              android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
              android:title="Share" />
          <item
              android:id="@+id/nav_send"
              android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
              android:title="Send" />
      </menu>
  </item>
  ```

Желательно поместить всё это нагромождение кода в `nav_header_main.xml`, тогда мы сможем вызвать его из `activity_main.xml` (как сейчас и сделано):

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

Итак, повторю вопрос: как правильно объединить xml-код из трех выше приведенных файлов в `nav_header_main.xml`?

Comment: Никак, иерархия не позволяет. Меню хмл должно находиться в меню хмл, иначе смысла от разделения не было бы. Всё в кашу ничем не лучше трех файлов.

Comment: Ну как сказать... Есть взять серьезное функциональное приложение, то там таких файлов может быть сотни... Если одно это меню даёт 3 дополнительных файла.